# Firebase Console Scheduled Cloud Messaging does not work after one day

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

[image] am facing a problem with the Firebase console Scheduled Notification. If I schedule a notification then it only works for that day only and after that, it does not work. What may be the possible reason for this? It was working earlier.